# Telegram API: Can I get historical user data for a channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

You can query the Telegram API for the *current* number of members in a Telegram channel. But is it possible to query for the number of members on past dates? Ideally, I would like to know the number of members on every day for the last year:

```
| Date       | Channel Members |
|------------|-----------------|
| 2020-07-28 |            1234 |
| 2020-07-27 |            1342 |
| 2020-07-26 |            1423 |
| ...        |             ... |
| 2019-07-28 |             123 |
```

Is there a way to retrieve this information via the Telegram API? I am using `telethon` on Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not possible using Telegram API. But you can use services that monitor stats for each channel they found. Try to Google for telegram channel stats, you will find some.

Telemetr is one of examples:
https://telemetr.me/

It’s also easily scrape-able, but you have to check if that doesn’t violate their terms.

Comment: how come telemetr hasn't violated it then